# Sort values in PySpark RDD without using sort() function

Tags: sorting, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

```
a = sc.parallelize((11,7,20,10,1,7))
```

I want to sort the elements in increasing order without using sort() function.

I tried:

```
def srt(a,b):
if a>b:
    i=a
    a=b
    b=i   

final=a.map(lambda x,y: srt(x,y))
```

I am not getting the required result.

I want to get

```
  (1,7,7,10,11,20)
```

thank you.

Comment: Why can't you use `sort()`? Your code doesn't work because `rdd.map()`  is a function of only one variable.

Comment: I am just trying to understand how the map/filter/reduce works in pyspark. Thats why I am trying to sort it without the sort() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to avoid `sort()`, here is one way but I do not recommend using this at all.

First call `zipWithUniqueId()` to add a unique ID to each row. Then repeatedly append the minimum value in the `rdd` to a list until the size of the list is equal to the `count()` of the `rdd`:

```python
a = sc.parallelize((11,7,20,10,1,7))
a = a.zipWithUniqueId()

mins = []
curr_min = a.reduce(lambda x, y: x if x[0] < y[0] else y)
mins.append(curr_min)

while(len(mins) < a.count()):
    curr_min = a.filter(lambda x: all(x != m for m in mins))\
                .reduce(lambda x, y: x if x[0] < y[0] else y)
    mins.append(curr_min)
print([m[0] for m in mins])
#[1, 7, 7, 10, 11, 20]
```

This doesn't really sort your `rdd`, but it gets the values in sorted order. You'd have to parallelize the output to get back to an `rdd` if you'd like. But as I mentioned earlier, this is not a good approach to this problem. Just call `sort()` instead.